# Intersection between dynamical systems and stochastics?

Tags: stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems

Are there any subjects that deal with the intersection between dynamical systems and stochastics? (Specifically in pure mathematics.)

I know about random dynamical systems, but there does not seem to be a lot of papers or research on the topic. I was wondering if there were any other fields or topics that deal with a good intersection of both of these subjects.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out statistical mechanics? In my experience, I also know that the applications of uncertainty quantification and state estimation typically use the tools of stochastic dynamical systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you look for **smooth ergodic theory**.

See for example the collection of papers in the proceedings [Smooth Ergodic Theory and Its Applications](https://bookstore.ams.org/pspum-69) that although from 2001 can give a feeling of many of the topics that are studied in the area.
This includes the study of the ergodic/statistical/stochastic properties of a smooth dynamical systems preserving a finite measure. The invariance translates to the identical distribution of certain random variables, if you prefer that other language.

Depending on your background, the book by Barreira and Pesin, [Introduction to Smooth Ergodic Theory](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-148) might be a good entry point.

The huge area of *random dynamical systems* although now somewhat out of fashion, it seems, can be seen as a subfield of smooth ergodic theory (although I realize that this may be a matter of opinion!). I recommend that you have a look at the book by Ludwig Arnold, [Random Dynamical Systems](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540637585).

Comment: Awesome! My soon to be advisor studies stochastic pdes (and he is extremely knowledgeable on analysis and measure theory) and I heard these two fields overlap a lot!